# How to randomize items and then remove from a Swift array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, random

I have an array of fruits. I am fetching a fruit randomly (see following codes). Question: How do I remove this fruit from the array after fetching it?

```
let fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple", "lemon" ]

func getRandomFruit() -> String {
    let randomFruit = fruits.randomElement()!
    return randomFruit
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do it just like a deck of cards. Instead of `randomElement` use `shuffle` and just remove the last element.

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple", "lemon" ]
fruits.shuffle()
let myfruit = fruits.popLast()
```

(Just keep doing that as needed. `myfruit` will be `nil` if you've emptied the list.)

Comment: Hmm...very clever.

Comment: @Eric33187 not really, it’s standard operating procedure

Comment: Thanks Matt ... yes precise and concise.

Comment: OK. And then, after a round of removing all fruits, how do you repopulate the array to its initial state?

Comment: Well you’d have kept a copy safe somewhere. :)

Comment: Well I presume there is no clever codes to resume the array then :(

Answer (score 2):

No need to shuffle the whole collection to remove an element. Just get a random index, return that element and defer the removal of that element:

```
func getRandomFruit() -> String? {
    guard let index = fruits.indices.randomElement() else {
        return nil
    }
    defer { fruits.remove(at: index) }
    return fruits[index]
}
```

---

```
var fruits = ["apple", "orange", "banana", "pineapple", "lemon" ]
```

---

```
let fruit1 = getRandomFruit()   // apple
let fruit2 = getRandomFruit()   // lemon
let fruit3 = getRandomFruit()   // banana
let fruit4 = getRandomFruit()   // orange
let fruit5 = getRandomFruit()   // pineapple
let fruit6 = getRandomFruit()   // nil
```

Comment: Thanks Leo. It works.

Comment: regarding the question you asked Matt https://stackoverflow.com/a/64398344/2303865

Comment: Thanks Leo. This way, array.count stays the same and the array can be reused. No problem about "repopulating".